# Get String as Path

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to correct this code:

```
Dim ab2 As String
ab2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value 
Dim ObjFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder

Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder(ab2)


Call getfiledetails(objFolder)

End Sub
```

My Target is to assign the value of cell b2 (which is a folder location) to my

`objFolder.ObjFSO.GetFolder(ab2)`

But I am having the "Path Not Found" Error.

I also used `objFolder.ObjFSO.GetFolder&ab2` but I get a different error message.

Any idea on how to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact value of `ab2`?

Comment: ("D:\Projects\Working Files\") is the value. :)

Comment: And you get the error in this line `Set objFolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder(ab2)`? • Test if setting the path directly (not reading from the sheet) `ab2 = "D:\Projects\Working Files\"` works. If not your folder does not exist, or you don't have the permissions for that path.

Comment: Provided `ab2` doesn't **contain** the quotes and parentheses you mention in your comment, then check cell `B2` for hidden characters by checking the `LEN(ab2)` - if it's not 26 there there's something in there that shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you CLR and PEH, the " " was the error. I did not foresee that. Thank you for helping me.